# why this php string giving error?

Tags: php

hi friends why this php string error ?

```
echo  '<div id="album_list"><a href="view_gallery/album_pix/ .$v['id']. ">' . $i . ' ' . $v['album_name']. '</a></div>';
```

Comment: An IDE with syntax highlighting will show you. `.$v['id']`

Comment: You can see the problem from the sole syntax highlighting.

Comment: Um, what error? (I know what error, but you should at least tell us what error for the benefit of the doubt.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a single-quote after `album_pix/` and before the closing bracket.

```
echo  '<div id="album_list"><a href="view_gallery/album_pix/' .$v['id']. '">' . $i . ' ' . $v['album_name']. '</a></div>';
```

Answer (score 3):

You have some missing single quotes.

```
echo  '<div id="album_list"><a href="view_gallery/album_pix/ .$v['id']. ">' . $i . ' ' . $v['album_name']. '</a></div>';
//                             you need a single quote here ^          ^ and here
```

Answer (score 0):

- Single quote the string with the double quotes and attributes
- Single space and concatenate with the period .
- Change $var['key'] to $var, or $var["key"]

I'd change your variable names to reduce the confusion. As someone said above syntax highlighting will turn all the strings one color, and the variables another. Stack Overflow even displays code as such.

```
<?php

$v_id         = $v['id'];
$v_album_name = $v['album_name'];

echo  '<div id="album_list"><a href="view_gallery/album_pix/' . $v_id . '">' . $i . ' ' . $v_album_name . '</a></div>';

?>
```